# ASP.Net MVC 4 Manage Roles - Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sqlroleprovider

I have a MVC 4 web application which I want to implement `SqlRoleProvider` and `Windows Authentication` into it. 
After I did search in Google I added `SqlRoleProvider` tables in my database by running `aspnet_regsql` command in VS command prompt.
Then I added this to my `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="PortalDbContext" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now I need to know how can I manage roles? I mean how to create/edit/delete roles and assign/un-assign users from roles? 
Should I create these pages by myself or there is something already available may be with `NuGet`?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just roll my own. And this has been years, not sure if its supported anymore, but you can use the [Asp.Net Web Site Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228053%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if your on IIS. It's slow and clunky but if I recall get's the job done.